# pandas の Seriesクラスの`groupby`メソッドの使い方

Tags: python, pandas

## 環境

- Python3.6.5
- pandas 0.23.0

## 背景

普段はDataFrameの`groupby`メソッドを使っています。
最近、Seriesにも`groupby`メソッドがあることを知り、使ってみようと思います。

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html

## 質問

pandasのSeriesクラスの`groupby`メソッドは、どのように使えばよろしいでしょうか？

以下のコードを実行すると、「by or levelが必要」というエラーが出ます。

```
s = pd.Series(["a","a","b"])
s.groupby()
#TypeError: You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'
```

マニュアルで`by`の説明を見ましたが、よく分かりませんでした。
`by`にはどういった情報を渡せばよいでしょうか？

> by : mapping, function, label, or list of labels
>
> Used to determine the groups for the groupby. If by is a function,
>   it’s called on each value of the object’s index. If a dict or Series
>   is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the
>   groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method). If
>   an ndarray is passed, the values are used as-is determine the groups.
>   A label or list of labels may be passed to group by the columns in
>   self. Notice that a tuple is interpreted a (single) key.

## やってみたこと

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483670/how-to-group-a-series-by-values-in-pandas

上記サイトを見て、以下のようなコードでgroupbyすることはできました。
しかし、`groupby`メソッドに自分自身のSeriesを渡して、なぜgroupbyできるかが分かりませんでした。

```
s = pd.Series(["a","a","b"])
print(s.groupby(s).count())
a    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようにしてみればわかるのですが、`Series`の`groupby`は、配列で渡した場合はそれで`Series`を`groupby`しています。`If an ndarray is passed, the values are used as-is determine the groups.`という記述と合致していています。

```
>>> s = pd.Series(["a","a","b"])
>>> for i in s.groupby([10, 11, 11]):
...   print(i)
...
(10, 0    a
dtype: object)
(11, 1    a
2    b
dtype: object)
```

また、辞書で渡す場合は、以下のようにすると上と同じ結果になります。これは、`If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method).`という説明と合致します。

```
>>> for i in s.groupby({0:10, 1:11, 2:11}):
...   print(i)
...
(10, 0    a
dtype: object)
(11, 1    a
2    b
dtype: object)
```

自分自身のSeriesを渡すと以下のようになります。

```
>>> for i in s.groupby(s):
>>>   print(i)
...
('a', 0    a
1    a
dtype: object)
('b', 2    b
dtype: object)
```

なお、Seriesの要素の出現回数が必要な場合は通常`value_counts()`を使います。

```
>>> s.value_counts()
a    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```